# nginx return 200 if rewrite_by_lua_block response header contains pattern

Tags: nginx, lua, google-compute-engine, openresty

I need nginx to return 200 code on some location only if `rewrite_by_lua_block` response contains custom header with pattern (for google compute engine balancer healthcheck).

I'm very newbie in lua, so any help's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to try (untested)

```
header_filter_by_lua_block {
   if ngx.status == 200 then
      local from, to, err = ngx.re.find( ngx.header.Foo, "your_regexp_here")
      if not from then
         ngx.status = 500 -- use the error code you need
      end
   end
}
```

Keep in mind - your should place `header_filter_by_lua_block` directive into location where your request is really sent to upstream, say where you redirect to by `rewrite_by_lua_block`.